# Wordpress - Travelify - Title is appearing 3 times in blogpost

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have problem with free theme on wordpress - Travelify. After update Title is appearing 3 times in blogpost.

Now we reporting this problem on support forum for this theme, but nothing change.

Is possible any "hot fix" for delete the two other?

Red titles ill delete

[image: Red titles ill delete]

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is for now downgrade the theme with plugin "WP Rollback".